# Newsletter subscriber email to Admin

Tags: magento-2.1, email, newsletter

I am using Magento 2.1.5, and I need to send email to admin after every 15 days with the list of new subscribers.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In magento, you cannot get last 15days  list of new subscribers list because of there are not `created_at` column at database table `newsletter_subscriber`. **So you cannot filter collection by date**.

**To achieve this requirement, you need to create a custom module.** Where 
You need create  column  using installer script

Module's basic files:

- `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/registration.php`
- `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/composer.json`
- `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/etc/module.xml`

First create  an `UpgradeSchema.php`file at `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/Setup`.

```
<?php
namespace {vendorname}\{Company}\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

   public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
        $connection->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('newsletter_subscriber'),
            'creation_time',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                'default' =>  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT,
                'comment' => 'Creation Time'
            ]
        );

    }
}
```

In this module, create a cronjob which will send the list of new subscriber to admin

- `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/etc/crontab.xml` **Used to define cron**
- `app/code/{vendorname}/{Company}/Cron/Sendnewsletterlist.php` Php class  of cronjob which send the list of new subscriber to admin

Comment: Can we create this as plugin in my existing module???

Comment: can you please help me little bit, what will be code in Sendnewsletterlist.php

Comment: will update Soon....